# Why does BIOS created Raid0 array shows as Non-Raid in Ubuntu 22.02

Tags: partitioning, raid, bios, fakeraid

I have 1 of 1TB m.2 and 2 of 500gb m.2
Why does BIOS created Raid0 array(500x2) shows as Non-Raid in Ubuntu 22.04?
Here is the result from sudo lsblk

```
nvme1n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
└─nvme1n1p1 259:3    0 931.5G  0 part /media/cache
nvme0n1     259:1    0 476.9G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1 259:2    0 476.9G  0 part
```

Moreover, even when I boot without doing the BIOS raid 1 of 500gb nvme always missing
More information on this;
Mobo is Asus prime x570-p newest BIOS version
Both of the 500gb nvme show as working properly when installed 1 by 1 but when installed both only 1 shows. Even when created in BIOS as you can see from sudo lsblk result
Tried enable/disable ACHI/Raid mode both ways but problem never solved